# Get-VM is doing nothing for Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0, hyper-v

We have [Windows 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 on our server. We are trying to write a PowerShell script to start/stop our VMs, but the get-vm command isn't working. There is no error message. The command is just not returning anything, but should be.

The code looks like this:

```
$temp = Get-VM -Server usa..... | where-object {$_.State -eq 'Running'}
```

We tried doing

```
$temp = Get-VM -name VM-VMNameAsSeenInHyperVMgr
```

and it doesn't return anything either.

We installed the update for PowerShell to get version 3 and that made the get-vm command work (not give error message), but it's still not returning any VMs.

I saw the forum post *[PowerShell "Get-VM" error](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/07decd82-270e-4dd0-b8e8-789d693099dd/powershell-getvm-error?forum=winserverpowershell)*.

But Hyper-V is installed now and shows up when I type at the PowerShell command line

```
Get-Module  -listavailable
```

At the start of my code I have

```
import-module Hyperv
```

There's also this:

```
[system.net.dns]::GetHostEntry(ip)
```

works and so does [Get-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849946.aspx).

We tried

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

but the command wasn't recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

I tried disabling UAC like this link , but it didn't work. This link shows commands I used:  http://www.ehloworld.com/1026

When I typed

```
Set-UACStatus -Computer usa...net -Enabled [$false]
```

it gave the error message that Set-UACStatus wasn't recognized as the name of a cmdlet, etc. either. It didn't recognize Get-UACStatus either.

I'm not sure if there's another thing I need to import to use Get-VM. Or my co-worker was thinking maybe we're running into unknown AD issues. I think if it was Active Directory, it would be giving an error message about not having permission to do something, but it's not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out.

I needed to run PowerShell as administrator and then the Get-VM returned the list of VMs. I found the answer in forum post *[Get-VM doesn't work](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/it-IT/586083bc-d3c7-4d77-a98b-e62939552afd/getvm-doesnt-work?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv&prof=required)*.